# Prisma - How to efficiently select on multiple many-to-many conditions

Tags: express, prisma

I have two models in my Prisma database explicitly with an explicit many-to-many relation.

```
model User {
    id String @id @default(uuid())
    username String @unique
    clubs UsersToClubs[]
}

model Club {
    id Int @id @default(uuid())
    name String
    users UsersToClubs[]
}

model UsersToClubs {
    user User @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
    user_id String
    club Club @relation(fields: [club_id], references: [id])
    club_id Int
    @@id([user_id, club_id])

    @@index([user_id])
    @@index([club_id])
}
```

If I have a list of club ids, how do I efficiently find all users in all of the clubs? I'm particularly thinking about if scaled up, there may be x clubs, 10,000x users, each club could have up to 100x users, and each user could have up to 10-15 clubs. So ideally, we would not search the User table since there are a lot of them. However, I'm not sure how to search the list of Users in each club and find common users efficiently.

Note: I will be applying multiple similar filters when searching for Users (same setup as with Users), so efficiency is important here.

I thought about searching through the User table for users that have all the clubs, but that would be very inefficient when scaled up. I also considered getting the list of Users from each club, and then finding the ones in common, but that could also be inefficient due to the sheer number of Users in each club.